# How do I extract the real-time FileIO state from Akka?

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream

I am making a file transfer system using Akka. I've been looking at the documents for a while. The current status of progress is Actor2 received the file sent by Actor1 and wrote it to the local system of Actor2 (Actor1 = sender, Actor2 = receiver).

But I couldn't find a way to know how much byte I received in real time when writing.

I tested it, and it turns out, with `runWith` API, files can be written locally. With `runForeach` API, how much byte was delivered in real time through. However, if these two are created at the same time, the file cannot be written.

Here's my simple source. Please give me some advice.

```
public static Behavior<Command> create() {
    return Behaviors.setup(context -> {
        context.getLog().info("Registering myself with receptionist");
        context.getSystem().receptionist().tell(Receptionist.register(RECEIVER_SERVICE_KEY, context.getSelf().narrow()));
        Materializer mat = Materializer.createMaterializer(context);

        return Behaviors.receive(Command.class)
                .onMessage(TransferFile.class, command -> {
                    command.sourceRef.getSource().runWith(FileIO.toPath(Paths.get("test.pptx")), mat);
                    //command.replyTo.tell(new FileTransfered("filename", 1024));
                    command.sourceRef.getSource().runForeach(f -> System.out.println(f.size()), mat);
                    return Behaviors.same();
                }).build();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`BroadcastHub`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-dynamic.html#using-the-broadcasthub) to allow multiple consumers of your `Source`:

```
Source<ByteString, NotUsed> fileSource = command.sourceRef.getSource();

RunnableGraph<Source<ByteString, NotUsed>> runnableGraph =
  fileSource.toMat(BroadcastHub.of(ByteString.class, 256), Keep.right());
// adjust the buffer size (256) as needed

Source<ByteString, NotUsed> fromFileSource = runnableGraph.run(mat);

fromFileSource.runWith(FileIO.toPath(Paths.get("test.pptx")), mat);
fromFileSource.runForeach(f -> System.out.println(f.size()), mat);
```

Comment: Thank you!
I applied it with the code you told me, and the function I wanted works exactly!

Did you learn about AKKA by yourself? haha :)

I respect and thank you as a beginner of AKKA.

Answer (score 1):

`BroadcastHub` as suggested by Jeffrey, allows for a single running stream to be connected to multiple other streams that are started and stopped over time.

Having a stream that dynamically connects to others requires quite a lot of extra hoops internally, so if you don't need that it is better to avoid that overhead.

If you use case is rather that you want to consume a single source with two sinks that is better done with `source.alsoTo(sink1).to(sink2)`.

`alsoTo` in the flow API is backed by the [Broadcast](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Broadcast.html) operator, but using that directly requires that you use the Graph DSL.

Comment: I didn't think about overhead. Thank you for your advice :)
But I don't know how to change it if I want to do as you advised.
Can you give me some advice?

Comment: Something like, `command.sourceRef.getSource().alsoTo(Sink.foreach(...println)).runWith(FileIO...)` you should probably look in to the materialized value of the file operator as well so that you notice if there is an exception.